# Grails - Jasper plugin dependency download error

Tags: java, maven, grails

I'm trying to download jasper plugin for grails but if I put the dependency in my build.gradle I keep getting this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'Eventos Unipar'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtime'.
   > Could not find org.olap4j:olap4j:0.9.7.309-JS-3.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/C:/Users/xSlok/.m2/repository/org/olap4j/olap4j/0.9.7.309-JS-3/olap4j-0.9.7.309-JS-3.pom
         file:/C:/Users/xSlok/.m2/repository/org/olap4j/olap4j/0.9.7.309-JS-3/olap4j-0.9.7.309-JS-3.jar
         http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/org/olap4j/olap4j/0.9.7.309-JS-3/olap4j-0.9.7.309-JS-3.pom
         http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/org/olap4j/olap4j/0.9.7.309-JS-3/olap4j-0.9.7.309-JS-3.jar
     Required by:
         eventosunipar:Eventos Unipar:0.1 > org.grails.plugins:jasper:1.11.0 > net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:5.6.1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output
```

the dependency I'm using is

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:jasper:1.11.0"
```

and the url for the maven repository I'm using is

```
http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo
```

already tried with this one too

```
http://repo.grails.org/grails/core
```

does anyone know what's happening?

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes the library of jasper in the grails repo get broken.

To solve this problem you just need to add this repo:

`http://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts`

I hope this solve your problem

**Reference:** http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/826431/failure-find-orgolap4jolap4jjar097309-js-3

Answer (score 4):

At today I am answering, the following link works

```
mavenRepo("https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try excluding olap4j.

```
implementation(group: 'net.sf.jasperreports', name: 'jasperreports', version: '6.1.0'){
            exclude module:'olap4j'
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Import maven

```
   <repository>
        <id>jr-ce-releases</id>
        <url>https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/</url>
    </repository>
```

Answer (score -1):

Jaspersoft has changed his repository to https:

https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/ui/native/third-party-ce-artifacts
(Edited)

Comment: Sorry, but this can't be or is no longer correct as your URL produces a HTTP 404